# How to check in MongoDB C# Driver if updated successfully?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using the following code to update data  using the MongoDB C# Driver:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateFirstName(string id, string firstName)
    {
        await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(
            "_id", new ObjectId(id)),
            Builders<User>.Update.Set("firstName", firstName)
            .CurrentDate("lastUpdatedDate"));
    }
```

This method returns "bool", because I want to know if the data has been updated successfully. This would be the pseudocode for checking if the data has been updated successfully:

```
    if (data updated successfully)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to write the code for checking if the data updated successfully? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean 'updated successfully' ?? The information is entered in MogoDB ? The same information you send _is_ now in MongoDB ? Don't you believe in MongoDB doing it work ? Strange question: is what I'm doing is what I'm doing ?

Answer (score 1):

If the method was executed so the update was done, otherwise the method will throw an exception - In case of async it's important to not forget the await (since using async method without await can't ensure your application stay around long enough to retreive the exception)

Answer (score 0):

UpdateOneAsync has a return value of UpdateResult?, which gives you access to the ModifiedCount. As you you UpdateOne a single greater 0 check is enough.

```
 var response =  await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(
        "_id", new ObjectId(id)),
        Builders<User>.Update.Set("firstName", firstName)
        .CurrentDate("lastUpdatedDate"));

 if response.ModifiedCount > 0 {
 // success
 }
 // failed
```

This will throw an Exception if the Update is not acknowledged.